# Java Android simple refactoring

Tags: java, android

How to improve the code below? I'm new to Java, coming from iOS background. I think intent needs to go to a separate variable.

```
    public void activityOpener(int a) {

    if (a == 1) {
        Intent intent = new Intent (this, proj1new.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }else {
        Intent intent = new Intent (this, BasicNumbers.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Comment: This type of question is off topic here.  Try codereview.stackexchange.com

But for what its worth, its fine.  I'd have no problem with that on a code review.  Possibly factor out the common startActivity from both branches to below the branch, but either way makes very little difference.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'd refactor it like this:

```
public void activityOpener(int a) {
    Class<?> cls = a == 1
        ? proj1new.class
        : BasicNumbers.class;
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, cls);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Not much of a change, but it makes clear that only the new activity class depends on `a`.

If your style is to go for brevity, the whole thing can be reduced to a one-liner (at the expense of flexibility if you want to expand the logic in the future):

```
public void activityOpener(int a) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, a == 1 ? proj1new.class : BasicNumbers.class));
}
```

Comment: @KirillC - Oops. Yeah, I had an extra `this` argument in the second example (now removed).

Comment: Thanks, really good improvement. Looks like you can write Java just like Swift

Answer (score 1):

```
public void activityOpener(int a) {

    Intent intent;
    if (a == 1) {
        intent = new Intent (this, proj1new.class);
    }else {
        intent = new Intent (this, BasicNumbers.class);
    }
    startActivity(intent);
```

Is that what you mean? Code is now a bit cleaner

Comment: I think that answers my question, probably possible to improve even more